# What can generics do what you can't do with composition?

Tags: c#

Given a class:

```
public class TestMain
{

}
```

And two classes accepting instances of this class, one through generics:

```
public class Test1<T> where T : TestMain
{
    public Test1(T test)
    {

    }   
}
```

And one without:

```
public class Test2
{
    public Test2(TestMain test)
    {

    }
}
```

Why would you choose one over the other?

Comment: Would you ever want to have any derived `Employee` classes as a member of the class?

Comment: Read about C# generics: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Yes, there's a difference, as you can see. The code is different. Can you explain what we're seeing here and what you expect from all declarations?

Comment: What are the benefits of `List<Fruit>` vs. `ListOfFruits`? Would `List<TropicalFruit>` be useful? (by the way - `TestMain`, `Test1` and `Test2` are confusing names, and don't spark any intuition)

Comment: I believe they are essentially same. The `constraint` on class Test1 implies that  `T` cannot be other than `TestMain` and `T` is injected through constructor and 'Test2` basically injects `TestMain` directly through constructor without `generics (T)`

Comment: In principal it will be the same, the generics resolution will "create" a class `Test1'1` which by all means is the same as `Test2` (Actually the IL looks almost identical). As long as `T` is not present in any of the return values I fail to see a point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In *that* case it is quite useless... But let's say you have a method:

```
// In Test1<T>
public List<T> GetList()
{ 
}
```

vs

```
// In Test2
public List<TestMain> GetList()
{ 
}
```

and let's say you have a

```
public class TestSubclass: TestMain
{
}
```

Now, you could:

```
List<TestSubclass> list1 = new Test1<TestSubclass>().GetList();
```

vs

```
List<TestMain> list2 = new Test2().GetList();
```

See the different return types? If it is useful or not it depends on how you are structuring your program.

I'll say a more common case is when you add the `new()` generic type constraint:

```
public class Test1<T> where T : TestMain, new()
```

Now in `Test1` you could have:

```
public T GetNew()
{
    return new T();
}
```

This is a "trick" that `Test2` can't do, because it would always return a new `TestMain()`

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the generic variant takes on the *actual type* for `T`, where the other only exposes `TestMain`.

So say you'd add a property:

```
public class Test1<T> where T : TestMain
{
    public T SomeProperty { get; private set; }
    public Test1(T test)
    {
        SomeProperty = test;
    }   
}   

public class Test2
{
    public TestMain SomeProperty { get; private set; }
    public Test2(TestMain test)
    {
        SomeProperty = test;
    }
}
```

And say you'd introduce a derived class:

```
public class TestMain2 : TestMain
{
    public string Foo2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then in `Test2` you won't be able to access `Foo2` of `TestMain2.SomeProperty` without casting, whereas in the generic class `T SomeProperty` will expose the actual derived type with all its members.

Answer (score 0):

Generic illustration.

**Class declarations**

```
/// <summary>
/// some base class
/// </summary>
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public BaseClass()
    {
        this.Name = "I'm basic class";
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// inherited class 1
/// </summary>
public class CoolClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public CoolClass()
    {
        this.Name = "I'm cool class :)";
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// inherited class 2
/// </summary>
public class SadClass : BaseClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public SadClass()
    {
        this.Name = "I'm sad class :(";
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// container
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"> element type </typeparam>
public class UniversalContainer<T> where T : BaseClass
{
    public List<T> Container { get; private set; }

    public UniversalContainer()
    {
        this.Container = new List<T>();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
UniversalContainer<string> stringContainer = new UniversalContainer<string>();      // wrong
UniversalContainer<BaseClass> baseContainer = new UniversalContainer<BaseClass>();  // right
UniversalContainer<CoolClass> coolContainer = new UniversalContainer<CoolClass>();  // right
UniversalContainer<SadClass> sadContainer = new UniversalContainer<SadClass>();     // right

baseContainer.Container.Add(new BaseClass());   // right
baseContainer.Container.Add(new SadClass());    // right
baseContainer.Container.Add(new CoolClass());   // right

coolContainer.Container.Add(new BaseClass());   // wrong
coolContainer.Container.Add(new SadClass());    // wrong
coolContainer.Container.Add(new CoolClass());   // right

sadContainer.Container.Add(new BaseClass());    // wrong
sadContainer.Container.Add(new SadClass());     // right
sadContainer.Container.Add(new CoolClass());    // wrong
```

Comment: Can you explain what this code illustrates? Is it about co- and contravariance?